# Unable to Load DLL 'wpcap.dll'. The specified module is not found

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, npcap

I want to know which application installed this `wpcap.dll`. I can see it in some PCs in location c:\Windows\System32\Npcap and in others in `c:\Windows\System32`.

When I run my code (which has `DllImport("wpcap.dll")` ) in the first PC, this exception is thrown whereas it is not thrown in second PC.

Also, when I manually add the dll to first PC also, the same exception is thrown. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Never rely on the kindness of strangers to deploy the DLL you need.  They are not going to be around when you need them most.  Ensure you obtain and test with your own copy of the DLL, deploy it in the same directory as your EXE.  And note that winpcap is no longer maintained, their advice is to use npcap instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know which application installed this wpcap.dll

Google Said it is WinPcap

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap

You can try [this](https://kompkimi.ru/sovety/eto-polezno-znat/kak-ispravit-oshibku-wpcap-dll):

run cmd and execute command:

> regsvr32 wpcap.dll

Comment: I saw this on Google. But I could not find any option to uninstall and reinstall the same. There was no Winpcap or Pcap in my control panel

Comment: Maybe it's from [Npcap](http://npcap.org); is there an Npcap in the list of installed programs in Control Panel?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Yes. This helped. after installing winpcap from the site mentioned, my application is able to spot the Dll. Thanks :)